# Android-Studio (Git): *.iml file always gets committed, why?

Tags: android, git, gitignore

I am developing an app using Android-Studio. To version-control my code, I am using GitLab. So, I've created the following `.gitignore` file to avoid committing everything:

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# built native files (uncomment if you build your own)
# *.o
# *.so

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Ignore gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Crashlytics configuations
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Signing files
.signing/

# Eclipse Metadata
.metadata/

# Mac OS X clutter
*.DS_Store

# Windows clutter
Thumbs.db

# Intellij IDEA (see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067)
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/libraries/
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/.name
.idea/compiler.xml
.idea/copyright/profiles_settings.xml
.idea/encodings.xml
.idea/misc.xml
.idea/modules.xml
.idea/scopes/scope_settings.xml
.idea/vcs.xml
.idea/datasources.xml
.idea/dataSources.ids
*.iml

build/intermediates/dex-cache/cache.xml

.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
```

However, whenever I try to `commit-changes`, the commit includes the `build folder` and `.iml file` (highlighted in the attached image), even though they are stated in the `.gitignore` file.

How to make Android-studio ignore these files and folders ?!

Answer (score 0):

To get Intellij IDEA (and by extension, Android Studio) to completely ignore files and folders use the following in `Editor -> File Types -> Ignore Files and Folders`:

[image]

From https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/file-types.html:

> **Ignore files and folders**   :  In this text box, specify the files and
>   folders, which you want to be ignored by IntelliJ IDEA. Such files and
>   folders will be completely excluded from any kind of processing. By
>   default the list includes temporary files, service files related to
>   version control systems, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

> First commit any outstanding code changes, and then, run this command:
>
> git rm -r --cached .
>
> This removes any changed files from the index(staging area), then just
>   run:
>
> git add .
>
> Commit it:
>
> git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"

Complete Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1139797/5740760)